# Strange EXM Experience Editing behaviour with Linked Image

Tags: exm

I am using a `View Rendering` in my `EXM Email Campaign Template`.

I saw a recommendation for a hyperlinked image to use this syntax:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("URL", new { text = 
      @Html.Sitecore().Field("Image", new {style = "border:none;", width = "730"})
    })
```

Which works great apart from the fact if I edit the link it results in the image disappearing from the experience editor window or part of the hyperlink element appears.

If you close and reopen the `EXM Experience Editor` then it's all fine but it would be a very disconcerting experience for a content author.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After saving and closing and opening up the experience editor:
[image]

In another `View Rendering` - very similar markup:

```
<td align="center">
   @Html.Sitecore().Field("URL", new { text = 
               @Html.Sitecore().Field("ButtonImage", new { style = "border:none;" }) })
</td>
```

After editing the hyperlink I see part of the hyperlink element:
[image]

Again all fine after I save and close and come back to the editor.

Using `Sitecore 9.1.1 and SXA 1.8.1` (have had some buggy behavior with SXA in other aspects of EXM so I'm not sure if this is standard EXM behavior or a bug).

Comment: Hey @jen, we saw some similar symptoms when personalizing images on 9.0.x and was resolved with a JS hotfix from support.  Not sure if related, but worth running by support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirmed this is a **Sitecore Bug**:
`public reference number 95437`

And workaround provided for my view rendering markup:

```
@Html.Sitecore().BeginField("URL", new { HideDescription = true, haschildren=true })
       @Html.Sitecore().Field("Image")
@Html.Sitecore().EndField()
```